# Positioning of tool tip

Tags: html, css, tooltip

I have a sample application which renders a grid [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/bHxmU6rNIseuSm9vMuAC?p=preview.)

```
  cellDiv.innerHTML = '<span  data-tooltip="'+ tooltip +'" >'+params.value+'</span>';
```

On hover on each cell, I am supposed to show a tool tip. But I am not able to position the tooltip properly. The tooltip arrow is getting chopped off because of this.

Comment: Can you share the CSS that you've written for the above?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/bHxmU6rNIseuSm9vMuAC?p=info

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue and created a [demo for this](https://plnkr.co/edit/1iCTFpJ4U5gVAN9r?p=preview)

```
  position: fixed;
```

The position was changed to 'fixed' in the 'before' selector of the tooltip class.